# Probability of Converging to 0

Tags: statistics

Suppose that an insurance company provides a car insurance. A fixed amount of
premium, say, 10 dollars are collected each day, and the size Yi of the claims on day i follows the exponential distribution with mean 6 dollars. Note that from the law of large numbers, the insurance company, in the long run, will earn 5 dollars a day on average, and the business will thrive. In particular, if we denote the daily profit with Yi = 10−Xi, the probability P(Y1 + · · · + Yn < 0) that the company will suffer a loss after n days will converge to 0 as n → ∞. That is, {Y1 + · · · + Yn < 0} is a rare event for large n. We want to understand how quickly this probability becomes small as n grows.

(a) Compute the exponential rate at which this probability converges to zero, i.e., lim n→∞ (1/n)log P(Y1 +...+ Yn < 0).

Consider another insurance line, for which the claim size Xi follows Pareto distribution with the shape parameter 2 and the scale parameter 3.
(b) Approximately estimate the probability P(Y1+...+Yn < 0) for n = 100, 200, 500, 1000.

I know for part (a) I should use Cramer's theorem but I don't know what else to do.

Comment: $5+6=10$?  Can you check for a typo in the first paragraph? (I assume the 10 is right, but both the 5 and the 6 are suspect)... Also, I assume the first mention of $Y_i$ should be $X_i$?

Comment: Yes those are both typos and you are correct